# Objective-C: Use the Original Image Size After Capture

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I am making an app that uses the camera.
Everything is working well, but when i started to add the captured image on a `UIImageView` it resizes automatically with respect to the size of `UIImageView`.

What i want it to do is, use the original size of the captured image.

Here's my code:

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [insertPhoto1 setImage:image];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the contentMode of the imageView:

```
  insertPhoto1.contentMode=UIViewContentModeCenter;
```